# How to find all non duplicated items in an array of Strings?

Tags: java

I want to find all non repeating items in an array of Strings.
Suppose I've:

```
String[] str = {"Red", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Blue"};
```

I'd like to find *"Blue"* as it is not repeating again.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the complexity, how big would the array be? what is the required code complexity?

Comment: There are solutions like Map, custom functions, iterators but if you want to be fancy, go for regular expressions. Its a good exercise and you will enjoy learning regex.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution is to create the Map with String as a key and Integer as the value. You will have to iterate through the array and increase the amount of the String in a map.

```
String[] str = {"Red", "Red", "Green", "Green", "Blue"};
Map<String,Integer> stringsCount = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

for (String s : str){
    if (!stringsCount.containsKey(s))
        stringsCount.put(s, 1);
    else
        stringsCount.put(s, stringsCount.get(s) + 1);
    }
```

And then you can print every String which was counted only once:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : stringsCount.entrySet())
    if (entry.getValue() == 1)
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
```

Comment: Tx sir..
It was just so simple, i was trying to do this only..but it didn't came across me to use like this.

Comment: @ARP Could you accept my answer as the correct one? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- sort the array
- create an empty list
- iterate over the sorted array: if element == previous element then do nothing else add previous element to list

At the end of the iteration, the list will contain unique elements only.

Note that this (obviously) does not preserve the original order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashSet for this. For example, this should work:

```
Set<String> getUniqueWords(String[] words) {
    Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> foundWords = new HashSet<>();

    for (String word : words) {
        if (foundWords.contains(word)) { //O(1)
            uniqueWords.remove(word);    //O(1)
        } else {
            uniqueWords.add(word);       //O(1)
        }
        foundWords.add(word);            //O(1)
    }

    return uniqueWords;
}
```

So using this approach, you will have (theoretically) linear time complexity, since you get the unique words in a single loop through the array.